# Tkinter extracting tags for create image

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have buttons with different names which would trigger the following:

```
class CreateCanvasObject(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, image_name, xpos, ypos):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image_name = image_name
        self.xpos, self.ypos = xpos, ypos

        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('*image path*'.format(image_name)))
        self.image_obj = canvas.create_image(xpos, ypos, image=self.tk_image, tags=generate_ID(image_name))

        canvas.tag_bind(self.image_obj, '<ButtonRelease-3>', self.remove)

    def remove(self, event):
        self.canvas.delete(self.image_obj)

    def generate_ID(buffer_name):
        id_list.append(id_name)
        print(id_list)
        global id_number
        id_number = id_number + 1
        return id_name
```

My question is, if I would to use the tags to do deletion, how should I pass the parameter into self.canvas.delete().
I have tried various way but this is out of my programming knowledge. Will appreciate any help and apology if I missed out anything, I am still relatively new to SO.

Reason I wanted to use tags instead of the ID is I'm keeping track of the various images created (the list contain the same string as the tags), so when one of the image is deleted I also want to delete it from the list.

Comment: You can just pass the tags to `canvas.delete()`.

Comment: The problem isn't clear. Why don't you save the tag just like you save the id, and then use the tag just like you use the id?

Comment: @BryanOakley Hmm ok, let's say I have 3 images created each with different tag. Now I right click the 2nd image, what is the method to pass the tag of the 2nd image to canvas.delete()?

Comment: @acw1668 is there a way to pass the tag?

Comment: What do you mean *"to pass the tag"*? Pass to `delete()` like `delete(tags)`? Or anything else?

Comment: Why do you need to "pass" it? If it's stored as an object attribute (eg: `self.tag`), there's no need to pass it in. It's easy to do, but I don't see why you think you need to? It would help  if you created a complete [mcve] with a couple of checkbuttons.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh my, I was not aware I could use self.tag, sorry I'm still bad in python and programming in general